# Interactive Grid in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex, insert-update, interactive-grid

How can I handle insert update in Oracle Apex interactive grid with more than one table which is attached with inner join. If anyone have solution please reply.

Answer (score 2):

The source of the IG can be a query or a view on top of multiple tables. Basically this is the rule: if you can execute the update statement in sql on the source then the IG will be able to do it as well.

So it's easy to display some extra columns from another table - updating them will be a challenge. There are 2 workarounds

1. Create a view with an *instead of trigger*
2. Use custom pl/sql code to process the IG data on submit instead of the native process